# Idioms for DRY code inside trait implementations (rustlings example)

Tags: rust

I am currently making my way through the [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings). [`try_from_into.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/conversions/try_from_into.rs) asks us to implement [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) for a tuple, and array, and a slice. The array and slice versions fit nicely into an `iter/map/collect` pattern, e.g. as follows:

```rust
// Array implementation
impl TryFrom<[i16; 3]> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(arr: [i16; 3]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        match arr
            .iter()
            .map(|x| u8::try_from(*x))
            .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        {
            Ok(v) => Ok(Color {
                red: v[0],
                green: v[1],
                blue: v[2],
            }),
            _ => Err(IntoColorError::IntConversion),
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=248e405a63021393d132002c1c5a160f)</sup>

Possibly this is not idiomatic either, so I'd appreciate any corrections.

However, the tuple implementation seems to leave me with two choices:

1. Put the tuple (of 3 `i16`s) into an array and then use the `map` pattern above. This seems wasteful.
2. Repeat myself by converting each value to `u8`, checking the result, and assigning to a local variable, e.g.

   ```rust
   fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
       let red = match u8::try_from(val) {
           Ok(v) => Ok(v),
           _ => return Err(IntoColorError::IntConversion),
       };
       let green = ...
       let blue = ...
       Ok(Color { red, green, blue })
   }
   ```

My first instinct is to put the `match` code into a helper and inline it if the language supported doing so, but Rust seems to have some barriers to that:

- [Private trait methods are not allowed](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/helper-method-for-a-trait-impl/7509), so I can't just add a helper inside the implementation. However, I lose any notion of what `Self::Error` is outside of the implementation.
- We [can't use generic parameters from outer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47967549/12162258), so neither can I create an inner function which uses `Self::Error` in the `try_from` definition, e.g. like

  ```rust
  fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
      #[inline]
      fn i16_to_u8(val: i16) -> Result<u8, Self::Error> {
          match u8::try_from(val) {
              Ok(v) => Ok(v),
              _ => return Err(IntoColorError::IntConversion),
          }
      }

      let red = i16_to_u8(tuple.0)?;
      ...
  }
  ```

What are the Rust idioms for avoiding repeated code inside trait implementations, especially where a helper method seems like the obvious choice to someone coming from languages where these are commonplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a little bit of a misconception of how associated types in traits work, because

> However, I lose any notion of what Self::Error is outside of the implementation.

is not strictly true. When you leave the trait's impl block, you don't lose the notion of `Self::Error`, you lose the notion of `Self`. You can create a helper function outside the the impl that refers to the type:

```rust
fn i16_to_u8(n:i16) -> Result<u8, <Color as TryFrom<(i16,i16,i16)>>::Error>{
    n.try_into().map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)
}
```

You can also make an associated function in a separate impl block for `Color`:

```rust
impl Color{
    fn i16_to_u8(n:i16) -> Result<u8, <Self as TryFrom<(i16,i16,i16)>>::Error>{
        n.try_into().map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)
    }
}
```

The associated type for a trait exists in all scopes the trait is in. In many cases, you do need the fully qualified syntax, `<Type as Trait>::Name` so the compiler knows which implementation's type to use (this occurs for `TryFrom` because of a blanket impl over `From`).

You can also manually desugar the type alias yourself, but it does reduce maintainability:

```rust
fn i16_to_u8(n:i16) -> Result<u8, IntoColorError>{
    n.try_into().map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)
}
```

Comment: This plays nicely off of John Kugelman's answer in that it explains how to implement free functions tied to `Color`'s error type. However, it is slightly wrong. For the free function, the compiler complains "ambiguous associated type ... help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<Color as Trait>::Error`", and something very similar for the method, which, by the way, should return a `Result`. I'm having a little trouble understanding quite what the help message is instructing me to do (what is `Trait` here?), if you wouldn't mind explaining.

Comment: Also small nitpick, the function should convert to `u8`, not `i8`.

Comment: @thisisrandy I addressed your comments (apparently I suck at proofreading), as well as added another solution I just thought of.

Comment: much better! I see what the `as Trait` bit was hinting at now, though I don't think I would have gotten there without some help. If you could change the input param from `n:u16` to `n:i16` in the latter two examples, I'll accept this answer, since I think it goes more directly to my original difficulty, which was not seeing how to write helpers other than the desugared variety you present in your third example. SO insists on edits longer than 6 chars, so I can't do it myself.

Comment: @thisisrand I fixed it, one of these days I'll figure out how to proofread properly.

Comment: One more question, actually. You recommend implementing `From<TryFromIntError> for IntoColorError` in the comments on John Kugelman's answer. I understand how to write the `impl` block and use it when chaining methods. However, in any of your examples, the function body that seems to work is `Ok(n.try_into()?)`, which just doesn't look right to me. Could you confirm that that's idiomatic or supply a better version if not?

Comment: It turns out rustlings deals with error type conversion only a couple of exercises hence in [advanced_errs_1.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/af91eb508ac659272398486f041b2a8364f9e385/exercises/advanced_errors/advanced_errs1.rs), and there's an example of `Ok(something()?)` at [line 40](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/af91eb508ac659272398486f041b2a8364f9e385/exercises/advanced_errors/advanced_errs1.rs#L40). Given that, I think I'm satisfied the pattern is idiomatic.

Comment: @thisisrandy You can use `n.try_into().map_err(From::from)` if you don't like using `Ok(n.try_into()?)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `match` block to a `?` if you map the error into an `IntoColorError`. That will allow you to continue chaining methods so you can call `try_into()` to convert the `Vec<u8>` into `[u8; 3]`, which can in turn be destructured into separate `red`, `green`, and `blue` variables.

```rust
impl TryFrom<[i16; 3]> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(arr: [i16; 3]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let [red, green, blue]: [u8; 3] = arr
            .iter()
            .map(|x| u8::try_from(*x))
            .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
            .map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)?
            .try_into()
            .unwrap();
        Ok(Color{ red, green, blue })
    }
}
```

I'd probably break that up into two or three separate statements myself, but you get the idea.

If you apply the same error mapping idea to the tuple case you can get it fairly compact. It's still repetitive but the repetition isn't too bad thanks to `?`:

```rust
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let (red, green, blue) = tuple;
        let red: u8 = red.try_into().map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)?;
        let green: u8 = green.try_into().map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)?;
        let blue: u8 = blue.try_into().map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)?;
        Ok(Color{ red, green, blue })
    }
}
```

You can see both implementations on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cb2e1a276ef346a77e6ca405b29d44a4).

It is possible to eliminate the repetitive `map_err` calls. If you're on nightly then you could use a [`try` block](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html) to capture the `TryFromIntError`s and convert them to `IntoColorError`s.

```rust
#![feature(try_blocks)]

impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let result: Result<_, TryFromIntError> = try {
            let (red, green, blue) = tuple;
            let red: u8 = red.try_into()?;
            let green: u8 = green.try_into()?;
            let blue: u8 = blue.try_into()?;
            Color{ red, green, blue }
        };
        result.map_err(|_| IntoColorError::IntConversion)
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bf5f2f816a69c80c3802f5640e7d6471)</sup>

On stable you could achieve the same effect with an immediately-invoked function expression, or [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression):

```rust
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = IntoColorError;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        (|| {
            let (red, green, blue) = tuple;
            let red: u8 = red.try_into()?;
            let green: u8 = green.try_into()?;
            let blue: u8 = blue.try_into()?;
            Ok(Color{ red, green, blue })
        })()
        .map_err(|_: TryFromIntError| IntoColorError::IntConversion)
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=afd9aac4edf9246f4d745a4211e14aaa)</sup>

---

> What are the Rust idioms for avoiding repeated code inside trait implementations, especially where a helper method seems like the obvious choice to someone coming from languages where these are commonplace?

Free functions. You can make helper methods outside the `impl` block.

Comment: You could also implement [`From<TryFromIntError>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.TryFromIntError.html) for `IntoColorError` to get rid of the `map_err`.

Comment: I see. I definitely found myself missing the `try/catch` mechanism that we see elsewhere, so I'm glad to see one is in the works/can be effected in stable.